# Multiple Spring Cloud Gateways. Can this configured as cluster?

Tags: spring, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-gateway

One option to make Spring Cloud Gateway highly available is to have multiple instances  backed by load balancer.
Is there a option to make cluster of multiple API gateway instances?
How will the load balancing works perfectly in case if API Gateways are not aware of each other , instead just do load balancing at each API gateway instance level

Comment: Why would they need to be aware of each other? All they do is route requests.

Comment: I have multiple API Gateways. Request is routed to API Gateway by a load balancer. API gateway way does routing and load balancing to services.If API Gateways are not aware of each other , can we have perfect load balancing?                                           
        Example API-Gateway-1 called Service-instance-1 . When next request reached API-Gateway-2, will this be aware of the previous request routing done by API-Gateway-1 and  so route the request to Service-instance-2

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Would depend on your lb strategy, and what you are using for Client side lb ( assuming you are using client side lb)

Comment: @123  Yes I am using Spring cloud loadbalancer for client side lb at gateway. Using Eureka  for service discovery

Comment: @amuru how were you able to make Service-instance-1 register to API-Gateway-1 and API-Gateway-2